# missing mutex lock error

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, coverity

i have a variable accessed via mutex lock in multiple threads.

when i run coverity static analysis on it, it gives the following error:-

**MISSING_LOCK (Accessing variable"g_atag"(g_atag) requires the osag_mutex.mutex lock.) [coverity]**

Code snippet:

```
unsigned long g_atag = 0;
pthread_mutex_t g_atag_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void get_atag(unsigned long *atag)
{
    int ret = -1;

    ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&g_atag_lock);
    if (0 != ret) {
        return;
    }

    if (g_atag < 10000) {
        g_atag++;
    } else {
        g_atag = 0;
    }

    *atag = g_atag;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_atag_lock);
}
```

Does any one sees any problem in this? i have added the locks then why is it saying the locks are missing?

Comment: the only thing that leaps out to me is the mutex isn't initialized with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`, and unless it is functionally initialized in some other function with `pthread_mutex_init()`, it will be a zero-filled structure, which may not be valid as "initialized" for your implementation (thus the reason the pthread spec provides the optional initializer construct).

Comment: Is there any other place where g_atag is accessed (read or write)? Do you know what osag_mutex is? Is there a typo in `if (gtag < 10000)`? Shouldn't it be g_atag?

Comment: i have tried with initializing it with PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER too. but no respite.. @lumpN -> yes thtat's a typo..correcting in the question

Comment: Ugh. My faith in Coverity is rapidly descending. (we actually use it at work, though its false positive ratio is a wee bit unacceptable to me). This looks correct to me, but... is this the only place that variable is ever *read* ? It would seem not, since this function returns a void, therefore somewhere else `g_atag` must be being used for its value. Where is that, and is it also protected by the same mutex ?? Or is the parameter for `atag` supposed to receive the value and that code is omitted? And if it is, how is the *caller* supposed to know `atag` was updated successfully ?

Comment: @WhozCraig - edited the post for your query. am returning the value of the variable in the parameter passed.

Comment: Not to beat a dead horse, but I caught it in formatting, so i may as well bring it up. I'll assume `g_tag` was supposed to be `g_atag` in the comparison expression.

Comment: There's nothing wrong lock-wise with the code as shown.  The complaint implies that `g_atag` is used with some other mutex elsewhere (is it? if it were static-duration and confined inside `get_atag` we could be sure it is not).  Unrelated: if `pthread_mutex_lock` fails, the function returns without setting any value in `*atag`.

Comment: Which line does the Coverity error refer to? Are you sure it's in that function?

Comment: @JonathanWakely - yes, it is throwing error in this function only at line "g_atag++;"

Comment: @torek - this variable is not used anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Can you post the event history for this?